# Need some information about running tor exit Relay

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays

I'm thinking about buying a computer to run an exit relay. I wonder what specs would be coherent ? Or should I use a VPS ? 
I have a 500mbps fiber connection at home.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't use your private home connection for running an Exit node! Exit nodes are blocked heavily and can expect many attacks. If you still want to use your own internet connection for normal activities like browsing or sending e-mails then allot of services will block you because they know your IP address is also running an Exit node.

Instead of running an Exit node you can always run a normal relay. With allot of bandwidth and good uptime (several weeks) your node can be selected as a Guard node as well. Still, on your private internet connection, you can expect some resistance. But not as much as an Exit node would get.

If you really do want to run a high bandwidth Exit node then take a look at the information from [IPredator](https://ipredator.se/guide/torserver). They show you what they did to run a good Exit node.

Answer (score 0):

The Tor website has some excellent tips for running an exit node if you want to do so:

1. Inform your potential ISP(s)

> In general, **running an exit node from your home Internet connection
>   is not recommended**, unless you are prepared for increased attention
>   to your home. In the USA, there have been no equipment seizures due to
>   Tor exits, but there have been phone calls and visits. In other
>   countries, people have had all their home computing equipment seized
>   for running an exit from their home internet connection. So you will
>   need to find a good colo and save your home connection for bridge or
>   middle node use. Plus, bandwidth will be much cheaper in a colo center
>   anyway.

2. Get a separate IP for the node. Do not route your own traffic via this IP.
3. Get recognizable Reverse DNS for this IP
4. Set up a Tor Exit Notice
5. Get ARIN registration (if possible)
6. Consider a Reduced Exit Policy
7. Rate limit and optionally QoS your node
8. Consider creating an LLC to run your node

You can read the entire article here:

https://blog.torproject.org/tips-running-exit-node